# Type '[Images]' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

I'm trying to pass array of objects through props but I got that error:

> (property) images: [Images]

> Type '[Images]' is not assignable to type'string'.ts(2322)

> ProductBlock.tsx(4, 5): The expected type comes from this index signature.

Here is my block:

```
interface Images {
    [key: string]: string;
}

interface Colors {
    [key: string]: string;
}

interface Product {
    _id: string;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    price: number;
    colors: [string];
    images: [Images];
    type: string;
    likes: number;
}

const ProductBlock = (product: Product) => {
    console.log(product.images); // [{...}]

    const RenderColors = () => {

    }
    
    const RenderImages: React.FC<Images> = (images: Images) => {
        console.log(images);
        return(
            <>
                
            </>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div className="product product-container" key={product._id}>
            <RenderImages images={product.images}/> //<--- Error here at "images="
            <h3 className="product-title">{product.name}</h3>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ProductBlock;
```

Comment: could you share what the console log returns?

Comment: which console.log ?

Comment: the product.images

Comment: it's array of objects, you can see it as comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

product.images is an array of Images objects, but you are passing it to RengerImages which is taking a single Images object as the parameter.

Try this:

```
const ProductBlock = (product: Product) => {
    console.log(product.images); // [{...}]

    const RenderColors = () => {

    }
    
  const RenderImages: React.FC<{ images: [Images] }> = ({ images }) => {
        console.log(images);
        return(
            <>
                
            </>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div className="product product-container" key={product._id}>
            <RenderImages images={product.images}/> 
            <h3 className="product-title">{product.name}</h3>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: so how can I fix it ?

Comment: There are a few ways, most straightforward would probably be to change RenderImages param type from Images to [Images]

Comment: like that: React.FC<[Images]> ?

Comment: My TypeScript is abit rusty but I think React.FC<[Images]> = (images: [Images]) or React.FC<Images[]> = (images: Images[]) should work

Comment: nope: Type '{ images: [Images]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & [Images] & { children?: ReactNode; }'.

Comment: I tried both and didn't work

Comment: Updated answer with code